# Unable to Play MP3 Song After Adding Artwork Using Mutagen

Tags: python, pytube, mutagen

I am utilizing the `pytube` library to download audio content from YouTube successfully. However, when attempting to add a thumbnail to the downloaded MP3 file using the `mutagen` library, the file becomes unplayable. The audio portion remains functional until the thumbnail is added, at which point the file appears to be corrupted or inaccessible. I also tried with `eyed3` but the same thing.

Code:

```
from os import rename
from os.path import exists, expanduser, splitext
from pytube import YouTube, Search
from requests import get
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

yt = YouTube(link)
print(f'Downloading...')
audio_stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
download_file = audio_stream.download(output_path=download_path)
base, _ = splitext(download_file)
out_file = base + '.mp3'
rename(download_file, out_file)

thumbnail = get(yt.thumbnail_url).content
audio = MP3(out_file, ID3=ID3)

if audio.tags is None:
    audio.add_tags()
    
audio.tags.add(
    APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/jpeg',
        type=3,
        desc=u'Cover',
        data=thumbnail
    )
)
audio.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert file to `mp3` format, not just rename file extension. You can use [pydub](http://pydub.com) lib for converting. Also make sure you have [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) installed.

```
import os
import pydub
import pytube
import requests
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
download_file = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path=download_path)
out_file = os.path.splitext(download_file)[0] + '.mp3'
pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(download_file).export(out_file, format='mp3')
audio = MP3(out_file, ID3=ID3)
if not audio.tags:
    audio.add_tags()
audio.tags.add(APIC(encoding=3, mime='image/jpeg', type=3, desc=u'Cover', data=requests.get(yt.thumbnail_url).content))
audio.save()
os.remove(download_file)
```